# Problemas en flutter y provider

Tags: flutter

ok te voy a compartir el repositorio e informacion mas completa:
Flujo de registro de usuario:
El usuario ingresa su correo electrónico, contraseña y confirmación de contraseña en la pantalla SignUpScreen.
Se llama a la función _signUpLogic.signUpWithEmailAndPassword para registrar al usuario.
Si el registro es exitoso, se envía un correo electrónico de verificación al usuario y se navega a la pantalla EmailVerificationPage.
El usuario debe verificar su correo electrónico haciendo clic en el enlace enviado.
Una vez que el correo electrónico está verificado, el usuario es redirigido a la pantalla CreateUser para completar su perfil.
repositorio https://github.com/CentenoDev/ITWANA-APP/tree/master

Comment: Creo que te has liado un poco. Deberias dde revisar las normas de este sitio para ver [como se puede hacer una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te puedan ayudar. Como no edites y expliques los problemas que esytas teniendo, es posible que incluso cierren tu pregunta.